# Contour selection in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a source image

[image]

I have applied a suitable threshold and got this

[image]

Now I used contour to find the inner black blobs. I used green color to signify outer boundary and red for the inner ones. This is what I got:-
[image]

I have extracted the blobs using the red color. But I would like to extract only those which doesn't have green inside them or at least give inner boundary only to ones that doesn't have another contour inside them. anyway to do it?

EDIT-1:- I thought of finding the coordinates of green and red pixels and converting all read pixels to green if they are very close to each other. but does anyone know how to get the coordinates?

EDIT-2 I followed Derman's method and I got 80% result. check out another source pic and its mask 
[image]
[image]

now following the inputs by Derman, I got this
[image]

the code clearly identifies contours marked 1 and 3(as green and red) based on the fact that they either have or dsnt have child contours. But contour 2 is clearly as same as contour 1 and has child contours but still it is taken as red. I will share you guys the code, I know that all it may take is a small modification but it seems elude me-

```
Mat binMask;    
Mat lung_src;   
vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
int count = 0;

findContours(binMask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (hierarchy[i][2] != -1) // means it has child contour
    {           
        if (count>1)// number of child countors,if its greater than 1 then green else red
        {
            drawContours(lung_src, contours, i, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());                
        }
        else  // means it's count is 1 or less
        {
            drawContours(lung_src, contours, i, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
        }
        count++;
    }           
    else  // means it doesn't have any child contour
    {
        drawContours(lung_src, contours, i, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }
}
imshow("lung", lung_src);
imwrite("lung.tiff", lung_src);
```

lung_src is the above shown red/green contoured image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For deciding whether one contour is inside another, you may use the contours' hierarchy structural characteristics. For instance, in your case, you may first detect contours using something like this:

```
cv::Mat inputImg = cv::imread("keVZc.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);    
cv::Mat binMask = cv::Mat::zeros(inputImg.size(), inputImg.type());
cv::threshold(inputImg, binMask, 28, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

cv::Mat cannyOutput = cv::Mat::zeros(binMask.size(), binMask.type());
cv::Canny(binMask, cannyOutput, 28, 28 * 2, 3);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(cannyOutput, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE,    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));
```

Then, using the hierarchy, you can decide whether that contour has parent, child, etc. The general structure of hierarchy is like this:

```
[next contour, previous contour, child contour, parent contour]
```

The `previous` and `next` contours are the ones belonging to the same level as the input contour. If the input contour has child, then it would give you the child label, or else, its value would be `-1`, which is similar case for parents.

So, you can check whether a contour is inside another like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if(hierarchy[i][2] != -1) // means it has child contour
    { 
        // do something with it
    }
    else  // means it doesn't have any child contour
    {
       // do something with it
    }
}
```

For comparing whether two contours are too close with each other in order to filter them out, you may use distance measurements (norm) between them. Something like this would help:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    int prvIndx = hierarchy[i][0]; // coordinates of previous contour
    int nxtIndx = hierarchy[i][1]; // coordinates of next contour

    std::vector<cv::Point> prvPoint = contours[prvIndx];
    std::vector<cv::Point> nxtPoint = contours[nxtIndx];

    // calculate norm of these two points
    double distance = cv::norm(point1, point2);

    // use a threshold value to decide what to do
    if(double <= 40.0) // change the value according to your situation
    {
        // you decide what to do here
    }

}
```

For more about contour hierarchy, take a look at the following references:

[ref1: Finding contours in your image](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

[ref2: Contours hierarchy](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html#gsc.tab=0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: In the parent section, the value indicates which contour is the parent. For instance, `[-1, 2, -1, 7]` means its parent is 7th contour. So, you can get the parent with something like `contours[7]`.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help :D

Comment: If you think my answer helped, please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @Derman- Hey,can you look into the code (from EDIT-2)?..I still have some doubts regarding it.

Comment: I believe you should double check the part for increasing your `count` value, and the `if-else` before `count++`.